# Use of DynamoDB annotations in nested objects

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to use DynamoDB annotations in nested objects as below:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName=xyz)
class entity1{
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
    private List<UserAction> userActions;
}

class UserAction{
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String actionId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    private Long createdTime;
}
```

I dont see the above attributes are auto generated in UserAction class. I would like to know if these annotation usages are supported in nested objects or not. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Add [@DynamoDbDocument](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBDocument.html) annotation on **UserAction** class. This annotation will ensure the instance of UserAction class is correctly serialized to a Dynamo DB sub-document before persisting in table.

---

```
@DynamoDbDocument
class UserAction{
    //...............
    //...............
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you but this dint help. I added that annotatiion you mentioned but no luck.

Comment: any idea about the sdk v2 equivalent of @DynamoDBDocument?

Comment: @AnweshMohapatra Check [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2265)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a v2 equivalent of `@DynamoDBDocument`, the following is the annotated way of doing it. For more information check [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2265) out.

```
@DynamoDbBean
class entity1 {
    
    private List<UserAction> userActions;
}

@DynamoDbBean
class UserAction {

    private String actionId;

    private Long createdTime;
}
```